# Set X Y cordinates of compoenents in JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

In Java, I can specify the location of a (for example) button somewhere in a panel. Is there an equivalent way of doing this in JSF?

Rephrasing the question:
For some type of panel (JSF component), can I specify the X and Y cordinates of where components in the panel should be placed?

I saw in PrimeFaces there is a Layout component. I was trying to add a button to it, but can not figure out a way to set the X and Y position.

Answer (score 2):

In general JSF is not responsible for positioning components, it simply creates HTML markup. With "in Java" you propably mean a Swing-GUI and more specific the NullLayout (?).

The standard way of positioning components directly in HTML (which JSF generates) is via CSS stylesheets and the "position" property (example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

You can put these positions into a separate CSS file or attach them directly to your JSF (or HTML) tags via the "style" attribute.

The layout tag from Primefaces tries to give you something like a LayoutManager in Java-Swing, whose main aim it is to avoid having to position things individually.

NOTE: As with a lot of HTML and CSS things, this may not work on every browser.